# Functions for outputting the rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: matrix, julia

I often want to iterate either row-wise or column-wise though a matrix in Julia, so I've created a pair of functions to help:

```
function cols(x::Matrix)
    function _it()
        for ii in 1:size(x,2)
            produce(x[:,ii])
        end
    end
    Task(_it)
end

function rows(x::Matrix)
    function _it()
        for ii in 1:size(x,1)
            produce(x[ii,:])
        end
    end
    Task(_it)
end
```

Example of use:

```
AA = [1 2 3; 1 2 3]

println("Columns are:")
for ii in cols(AA)
    println(ii)
end
println("\nRows are:")
for ii in rows(AA)
    println(ii)
end
```

Outputs:

```
Columns are:
[1,1]
[2,2]
[3,3]

Rows are:
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
```

---

Possible issues:

- It seems like this could be one function, that just takes the dimension as a parameter.
- This might confound the JIT, which would mean losing out out a bunch of speed. (The Julia JIT can normally vectorize `for` loops).
- I feel like there should be a inbuild function for this, but the closest I know of is [mapslice](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/?highlight=mapslice#Base.mapslices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most performant solution here would be to create an iterator:

```
julia> immutable EachRow{T<:AbstractMatrix}
           A::T
       end
       Base.start(::EachRow) = 1
       Base.next(itr::EachRow, s) = (itr.A[s,:], s+1)
       Base.done(itr::EachRow, s) = s > size(itr.A,1)
done (generic function with 48 methods)

julia> AA = [1 2 3; 1 2 3]
       for ii in EachRow(AA)
         println(ii)
       end
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
```

`EachCol` would be coded similarly.

---

This is advantageous over your task-based iterator design because Julia is not able to infer the return types from anonymous tasks.  This means that within your loop, the iteration variable `ii` is typed as `Any`, so the compiler isn't able to emit efficient type-specific code. The custom iterator is type-stable, so that means that Julia knows that the iteration variable is *always* going to be an array, allowing it to compile specific and optimized instructions.

To answer a few of your questions: We could similarly make an `EachDim` iterator which also stored the dimension parameter, but this is a little trickier to write in a type-stable manner.  Since indexing into columns returns a 1-dimensional column vector and indexing rows returns a 2-dimensional row vector, simply using an integer argument `1` or `2` to specify which dimension would result in a type-instability.  We'd need to ensure that the dimension information is stored in the *type-domain*.  One way to do this would be to use a parametric type… but doing this [nicely](https://gist.github.com/mbauman/8826ffc49ff631dbc008) requires the call-overloading feature from the development 0.4 version.

Also note that Julia's JIT doesn't "vectorize" for loops in the way you're using the word.  It can be thought of more as a just-barely-ahead-of-time compiler that compiles specialized machine code for each function based upon the types of the arguments.  This is why type-stability is so important; when Julia can infer the types precisely the compiled code is typically very similar to what you'd get from equivalent C code.